# Is there a reason http-proxy-middleware wouldn't proxy matching request?

Tags: flask, create-react-app, flask-socketio, http-proxy-middleware

I have a create-react-app front end that I need to proxy and change origin to my Flask socket-io back end during development to get around CORS.  I have already set up http-proxy-middleware which I have done in past projects with success.  My setupProxy.js:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function (app) {
    const wsProxy = createProxyMiddleware('/socket.io', {
        target: 'ws://localhost:5000/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        ws: true,
    });
    app.use(wsProxy);
};
```

I'm not doing anything special during socket setup:

```
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000/';
const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
```

When I run the dev server it will not proxy my socket io requests.  My server reports:

```
O _internal(113) _log(): 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2020 22:23:54] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NCRjjNJ HTTP/1.1" 400 -
O server(333) handle_request(): http://localhost:3000 is not an accepted origin.
```

Any thoughts on what I could be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

Have you done anything to configure cross-origin access in your Flask-SocketIO server? Add `cors_allowed_origins='http://localhost:3000'` to your `SocketIO()` object and then you should be fine.

Comment: That's what my temporary solution is, I've gotten http-proxy-middleware to work in the past and would really like to figure out the issue so that development is a bit easier.

Comment: You will need to inspect the headers to see where is the mistake. Clearly the server is receiving port 3000, but your changeOrigin option should have caused the origin to be on port 5000.